# ARRAYFORMULA, OFFSET, and Circular Errors

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm having trouble implementing a "Cash Out" feature in out party loot spreadsheet for my Pathfinder campaign. I keep running into circular references. The idea is that every member of the party gets their proportion of the party's liquid assets, unless they're in debt to the party. I'm using ARRAYFORMULA and MMULT to do these calculations, but I can't figure out how to reference the previous line in columns H through M from columns B through G. If I use OFFSET or VLOOKUP, I get circular reference errors. I just want to take the negative value of all positive numbers and put them in cells B through G, then everything else should work.

Here's a copy of the file. Feel free to mess around with it if you need to.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PPkZWR4HP3jbWyWDJMskbo3K1Px4CHCurgNZh3MTS-M/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Before you ask, I wasn't able to figure out how to adapt this answer to my purposes: [How to use ARRAYFORMULA with OFFSET to previous row without getting circular reference error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55268258/how-to-use-arrayformula-with-offset-to-previous-row-without-getting-circular-ref)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Just needed the right combination of the things I was already trying. The final formula was:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(SWITCH($T$2:$T,B$1,-($R$2:$R),"Cash Out",
IF(INDEX(MMULT(transpose(if(transpose(row($A$2:$A))>=row($A$2:$A),N(IF($T$2:$T = B$1,-($R$2:$R),$R$2:$R/6)), 0)),--(NOT(ISBLANK($R$2:$R)))),$A$2:$A-1)<0,0,
-(INDEX(MMULT(transpose(if(transpose(row($A$2:$A))>=row($A$2:$A),N(IF($T$2:$T = B$1,-($R$2:$R),$R$2:$R/6)), 0)),--(NOT(ISBLANK($R$2:$R)))),$A$2:$A-1))),
$R$2:$R/6)),COUNTA($R$2:$R),1)
```

The trick was using the MMULT method to generate the array of running totals above the cell I wanted to switch, then using INDEX and column A to specify which value I wanted. Using ROW() wasn't working. I've updated the sample file with the change.